# Wrong character encoding for Facebook Product Feed XML

Tags: xml, facebook, utf-8, rss, facebook-marketing-api

While trying to create a Facebook Product Feed according to this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-catalog/v2.10), it seems there is no reference to character encoding.

This is a Peruvian e-commerce site in Spanish. Using the XML below, there are errors for invalid characters, even though UTF-8 is being used.

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>Cuneo</title>
  <link>https://www.cuneo.com.pe</link>
  <description></description>
  <item>
      <g:id>Cun1003</g:id>
      <g:title>Anillo chevrón</g:title>
      <g:description>Anillo de plata 950, modelo chevrón. tallas 14 y 15.
      </g:description>
      <g:link>https://www.cuneo.com.pe/producto/anillo-chevron</g:link>
 <g:image_link>https://s3.amazonaws.com/mitiendape/uploads/tienda_000214/tienda_000214_120d6a4de1daf5ff29e623c00fc8860e706e6d0c_w300_h300.png</g:image_link>
      <g:mpn>CUN1003</g:mpn>
      <g:condition>new</g:condition>
      <g:availability>preorder</g:availability>
      <g:price>55.00 PEN</g:price>
      <g:google_product_category>.</g:google_product_category>
  </item>  
</channel>
</rss>
```

How should this feed be encoded?

Answer (score 1):

My server was sending response headers as

Content-Type:text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1

Change it to UTF-8 and the error was gone.